# Interpolate time series, select y value from x

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation

I have been searching for an answer to this for a while, and have gotten close but keep running into errors. There are a lot of similar questions that almost answer this, but I haven't been able to solve it. Any help or a point in the right direction is appreciated.

I have a graph showing temperature as a mostly non-linear function of depth, with the x and y values drawn from a pandas data frame.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = (22.81,  22.81,  22.78,  22.71,  22.55,  22.54,  22.51,  22.37)
y = (5, 16, 23, 34, 61, 68, 77, 86)

#Plot details
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7)), plt.plot(style='.-')
plt.title("Temperature as a Function of Depth")
plt.xlabel("Temperature"), plt.ylabel("Depth")
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.plot(x,y, linestyle='--', marker='o', color='b')
```

Which gives me an image somewhat like this one (note the flipped y axis since I'm talking about depth):

[image]

I would like to find the y value at a specific x value of 22.61, which is not one of the original temperature values in the dataset. I've tried the following steps:

```
np.interp(22.61, x1, y1)
```

Which gives me a value that I know to be incorrect, as does

```
s = pd.Series([5,16,23,34,np.nan,61,68,77,86], index=[22.81,22.81,22.78,22.71,22.61,22.55,22.54,22.51,22.37])
s.interpolate(method='index')
```

where I am trying to just set up a frame and force the interpolation. I also tried

```
line = plt.plot(x,y)
xvalues = line[0].get_xdata()
yvalues = line[0].get_ydata()
idx = np.where(xvalues==xvalues[3]) ## 3 is the position
yvalues[idx]
```

but this returns y values for a specific, already-listed x value, rather than an interpolated one.

I hope this is clear enough. I'm brand new to data science, and to stackoverflow, so if I need to rephrase the question please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may indeed use the [`numpy.interp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) function. As the documentation states

> The x-coordinates of the data points, must be increasing [...]

So you need to sort the arrays on the x array, before using this function.

```
# Sort arrays
xs = np.sort(x)
ys = np.array(y)[np.argsort(x)]

# x coordinate
x0 = 22.61
# interpolated y coordinate
y0 = np.interp(x0, xs, ys)
```

---

Complete Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = (22.81,  22.81,  22.78,  22.71,  22.55,  22.54,  22.51,  22.37)
y = (5, 16, 23, 34, 61, 68, 77, 86)

# Sort arrays
xs = np.sort(x)
ys = np.array(y)[np.argsort(x)]

# x coordinate
x0 = 22.61
# interpolated y coordinate
y0 = np.interp(x0, xs, ys)

#Plot details
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7)), plt.plot(style='.-')
plt.title("Temperature as a Function of Depth")
plt.xlabel("Temperature"), plt.ylabel("Depth")
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.plot(x,y, linestyle='--', marker='o', color='b')
plt.plot(x0,y0, marker="o", color="C3")
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

I think [Scipy](https://www.scipy.org/) provides a more intuitive API to solve this problem. You can then easily continue working with your data in Pandas.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
x = np.array((22.81,  22.81,  22.78,  22.71,  22.55,  22.54,  22.51,  22.37))
y = np.array((5, 16, 23, 34, 61, 68, 77, 86))

# fit the interpolation on the original index and values
f = interp1d(x, y, kind='linear')

# perform interpolation for values across the full desired index
f([22.81,22.81,22.78,22.71,22.61,22.55,22.54,22.51,22.37])
```

**Output:**

```
array([16.   , 16.   , 23.   , 34.   , 50.875, 61.   , 68.   , 77.   ,
   86.   ])
```

You can choose multiple other non-linear interpolations too (quadratic, cubic and so on). Check out the comprehensive [interpolation documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) for more detail.

**[Edit]**: You will need to sort your arrays on the x axis as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest adds.